# NoData values show up as values in ArcGIS Online map

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, nodata

I have a raster layer that I want to host as a web map and then host on a Arc Online Web Application. For some reason, my NoData values that appear transparent on ArcGIS Pro are showing up as a value of 1 (and therefore is a colour and not transparent in the ArcGIS Online Map).

Is there an easy way to make these values transparent on ArcGIS Online? I tried reclassifying the NoData values as values on ArcGIS Pro and then making them transparent as a work around. This worked ok for a small portion of the raster but isn't working for a large data set.

Comment: What format are you using?

Comment: Geodatabase @riflo

Comment: have you tried to configure the transparent value and create the .tpkx package?

Comment: Not sure how to configure the transparent value. Do you mean go to symbology and set it to transparent? If so, yes I have.  I gave upon creating a .tpkx package because it wasn't showing up on Arconline when I hosted it for some reason. It said it was uploaded but wasn't appearing online. So I switched to hosting a Web Map because I had success with that. @riflo

Comment: Yes, than export the project into a .tpkx package and upload the package in AOL. Test it with 5 images, remember that each upload will use credits.

Comment: Ok, I will try again. Does the size of the file matter? Gdb is around 3 GB.

Comment: i don't think so, the size matters in the calculation of credits. I suggest as a test don't use all scales so you will not consume a lot credits.

Comment: AH yes, now I remember why I gave up on creating Tpkx...the processing gets stuck at 100% and nothing happens. @Riflo